# Sort a dataframe based on a specific column in R with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```r
df <- data.frame(time=seq(1,4,1),col1=c("a","b","d","c"), col2=c("d","a","c","b"))
df
#>   time col1 col2
#> 1    1    a    d
#> 2    2    b    a
#> 3    3    d    c
#> 4    4    c    b
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I want to sort my data frame based on col2 and look like this

```
  time col1 col2 
    3    d    d
    1    a    a
    4    c    c
    2    b    b
```

Any ideas or help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Please explain what you mean, since there is no obvious `order`, `rank`, or other clear way to tie `c(3,1,4,2)` with `col2`'s `c("d","a","c","b")`. For instance, there *appears* to be a causative relationship between `col2` and `col1`, but that shouldn't be something inferred.

Comment: Thats a very good point r2evans. There is not a rationale really behind the data. I was mostly experimenting before going to bed and I was wondering if this is achievable. Please forgive if this sounds like a flub. I am happy to answer add more in your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know, if this makes any sense, but you could do a self join:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  select(col2) %>% 
  inner_join(df %>% mutate(col2 = col1), by = "col2") %>% 
  select(time, col1, col2)
```

This returns

```r
  time col1 col2
1    3    d    d
2    1    a    a
3    4    c    c
4    2    b    b
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution in base R:

```r
df <- data.frame(time = match(df$col2,df$col1),  col1 = df$col2, col2=df$col2)

#>   time col1 col2
#> 1    3    d    d
#> 2    1    a    a
#> 3    4    c    c
#> 4    2    b    b
```

Comment: Thnak you, Paul. It looks really neat!